# PHP - array associativo: verificar a quantidade de elementos dentro de uma value (que tem um array) de uma key

Tags: php, array, array-multidimensional, array-associativo

Eu tenho um array assim:

```
$array = array(
    user => "user1",
    name => "name1",
    books => "book1", "book2"
);
```

Eu quero ir em books e verificar o valor que elementos que tem dentro dele, no caso seria 2 (book1 e book2). Já tentei count(array['books']); e array['books'].length mas nenhum desses parece funcionar.
Eu gostaria de fazer essa verificação num if.

Agradeço qualquer contribuição.

Comment: Cara Sabrina não entendi, porque escolheu a outra reposta como correta? Ela não mostra em nada como "contar", não vou interferir no seu julgamento, mas simplesmente gostaria de saber aonde esta a motivação para isto e se realmente aquilo resolveu o seu problema.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isto não é um array dentro de outro:

```
 books => "book1", "book2"
```

Para ele ser um array teria que ser assim (ps: coloque aspas nas chaves também):

```
$array = array(
    "user" => "user1",
    "name" => "name1",
    "books" => array( "book1", "book2" )
);
```

Ou em php5.4+:

```
$array = [
    "user" => "user1",
    "name" => "name1",
    "books" => [ "book1", "book2" ]
];
```

Da outra forma que fez:

```
$array = array(
    user => "user1",
    name => "name1",
    books => "book1", "book2"
);
```

Seria o mesmo que:

```
$array = array(
    "user" => "user1",
    "name" => "name1",
    "books" => "book1",
    0 => "book2"
);
```

Aliais `array['books'].length` não funciona em PHP, isto é [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) provavelmente, não funciona dentro de PHP.

**Veja o exemplo online funcionando: https://ideone.com/0vnE3R**

A verificação em um `if` seria:

```
if (count($array['books']) == 2) {
    echo 'Contém 2 elementos';
}
```

Ou:

```
if (count($array['books']) > 1) {
    echo 'Contém 2 ou mais elementos';
}
```

Comment: É verdade, vou atualizar a pergunta.

Comment: Cara @SabrinaB. resolveu o problema? Testou desta forma o count?

Comment: sim, funcionou, obrigada.

Answer (score -3):

Sabrina, pode usar um comando chamado `foreach`

Seu `foreach` ficaria assim

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    foreach ($value as $keys => $valor)
    {
        //aqui você pega seu valor
    }
}
```